# State management issue within intersectionObserver's callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer, usecallback

I am trying to manage the index of the current page with state while implementing infinity scroll.

```
const [pageIndex, setPageIndex = useState<number>(2);

const getList = useCallback(async () => {
  try{
    // request api
    const {data} = await api(pageIndex);
    setPageIndex(index => index + 1);
  } catch(error) {
    // error handling
  }
}, [pageIndex]);

  const handleObserver = useCallback(
    async (
      [entry]: IntersectionObserverEntry[],
      observer: IntersectionObserver,
    ) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        await getList();
        observer.observe(entry.target);
      }
    },
    [getList],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loadMoreRef.current) return;

    const option = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 0,
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserver, option);

    loadMoreRef.current && observer.observe(loadMoreRef.current);

    return () => observer && observer.disconnect();
  }, [handleObserver]);
```

I wrote the code as above, but useEffect runs 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc., increasing by 1, and the state update is not done properly.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to reference and update the latest state value inside intersectionObserver's callback function.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a possible issue where updating the `pageIndex` state triggers all the callbacks to recompute and return new callback references, which eventually retriggers the `useEffect` callback. This might not be so ideal.

Assuming the `useEffect` hook and creating intersection observers logic is correct, I suggest using a React ref to cache the `pageIndex` state value such that its current value can be retrieved at any time in an enclosed callback handler. Remove all the dependencies from the `useCallback` hook so `getList` can be a stable reference for the life of the component.

Example:

```
const [pageIndex, setPageIndex = useState<number>(2);
const pageIndexRef = useRef<number>(pageIndex);

useEffect(() => {
  pageIndexRef.current = pageIndex;
}, [pageIndex]);

const getList = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    // request api
    const { data } = await api(pageIndexRef.current);
    setPageIndex(index => index + 1);
  } catch(error) {
    // error handling
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: ```tsx
useEffect(() => {
  pageIndexRef.current = pageIndex;
}, [pageIndex]);
```

There seems to be a bit of a typo in the code, can I use it as above?

Comment: @Hyeongrok Oh, sorry, there was a typo. It should be `pageIndexRef.current = pageIndex;`.